# How can I add a JavaScript tag attribute in Magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I'm trying to add CloudFlare's RocketLoader JS attribute tag `data-cfasync='true'` to some of my files manually.

I've learned how to load js files through layout.xml, but I'm not sure how to add the attribute through the XML.

What I have now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/js/prototype/prototype.js">
```

What I'm trying to get to:

```
<script data-cfasync="true" type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/js/prototype/prototype.js">
```

Comment: to which page you need to apply this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add this attribute `data-cfasync='true'` to the JS DOM nodes, there is no way.

The JS is created here:

```
\Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::getCssJsHtml
```

and the `sprintf` is resolved here:

```
\Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::_prepareStaticAndSkinElements
```

and I don't see any way to inject attributes, so I would suggest you rewrite the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` and change this method(s) as you need them.

Comment: It can't be added here?
'action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>mobilemenu/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name><params/></action>'

Thanks for your reply

Comment: correct, this is the method where the JS/Css generation starts in the very beginning. You add it all via `addItem/addJs/addSkinJs/addCss`, then it is added to an array, requested in the template and delivered by `getCssJsHtml` and finally created by `_prepareStaticAndSkinElements`